# How to filter and map nested array in a new data model?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an object which contains an array, inside this array I want to filter the objects based on a type.

I got this working with `.filter`. Then I want to add a property (array) of this object into a new object.

Basically what I want is filtering subItems by type and add subitems in the same structure as `currentElement`.

If a item contains sub items, this sub items must be added to a object in the same structure like `currentElement`.
`newElement` is what I want as result.

```
const currentElement = {
  items: [
   {
    name: 'item',
    subItems: [
     {
      name: 'item 1',
      type: 'item'
     },
     {
      name: 'item 2',
      type: 'item'
     }
    ]
    type: 'subItems'
   },
   {
    name: 'item',
    type: 'item'
   }
  ]
}
```

to be, what I expect:

```
const newElement= {
      items: [
         {
          name: 'item 1',
          type: 'item'
         },
         {
          name: 'item 2',
          type: 'item'
         }
      ]
    }
```

filter subItems and map as new element.

What I tried:

```
returnItems() {
    const items= this.currentElement.items.filter(item => item.type === 'subItems')
.map({subItems}) => subItems);
    
    return items;
 }
```

But this doesn't return what I expect, this returns an Array in Array. While I expect something like the `newElement`.

How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would be `Array::reduce` without any intermediate arrays:

```js
const currentElements = { items: [{ name: 'item', subItems: [{ name: 'item 1', type: 'item' }, { name: 'item 2', type: 'item' } ], type: 'subItems' }, { name: 'item', type: 'item' } ] };

const newElements = {items: currentElements.items.reduce((arr, item) => {
  if(item.type === 'subItems'){
    arr.push(...item.subItems)
  }
  return arr;
}, [])};

console.log(newElements);
```

And a benchmark:

```
` Chrome/118
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
reduce (Alexander)                          1.00x  |  x1   30   31   31   33   53
filter and flatMap (a tweak by Alexander)   5.53x  |  x1  166  174  177  181  204
filter and map (XMehdi01)                   5.80x  |  x1  174  190  203  205  210
flatMap and filter (XMehdi01)               8.23x  |  x1  247  276  291  307  307
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">
const elements = { items: []};
const chunk =  [{ name: 'item', subItems: [{ name: 'item 1', type: 'item' }, { name: 'item 2', type: 'item' } ], type: 'subItems' }, { name: 'item', type: 'item'}];
let i=1000000; while(i--) elements.items.push(...chunk);

// @benchmark filter and flatMap (a tweak by Alexander)
elements.items.filter(item => item.type === 'subItems')
  .flatMap(item => item.subItems);

// @benchmark filter and map (XMehdi01)
elements.items.filter(item => item.type === 'subItems')
    .map(item => item.subItems)
    .flat();
    
// @benchmark flatMap and filter (XMehdi01)
elements.items.flatMap(item => item.type == 'subItems' && item.subItems).filter(Boolean)

// @benchmark reduce (Alexander)
elements.items.reduce((arr, item) => {
  if(item.type === 'subItems'){
    arr.push(...item.subItems)
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

A variant to include the parent item into the result:

```js
const currentElements = { items: [{ name: 'item', subItems: [{ name: 'item 1', type: 'item' }, { name: 'item 2', type: 'item' } ], type: 'subItems' }, { name: 'item', type: 'item' } ] };

const newElements = {items: currentElements.items.reduce((arr, item) => {
  if(item.type === 'subItems'){
    const {subItems, ...parent} = item;
    arr.push(...subItems, parent);
  }
  return arr;
}, [])};

console.log(newElements);
```

Comment: Not as OP output asked, missing property `items`?*

Comment: @Alexander nice solution, most fast one. it's less readable but fast. :)

can you also add the option where the subitems are included in the parent items?

`items: [
{
"name": "subitem1"
},
{
"name": "subitem2"
},
{
"name": "item"
}
]`

Comment: @Can, yes, `Array::reduce` not the most readable way, but once you master it, it becomes very powerful

Comment: I will have a look and try to understand @AlexanderNenashev thanks.

Can you also add an example on how I can include the items + subitems?

Like this:
`items: [ { "name": "subitem1" }, { "name": "subitem2" }, { "name": "item" } ]`

Comment: @Can added to the answer (also it's the fastest again against `flatMap`!)

Comment: @Can I guess the problem is that `Array::reduce` constructs the result array directly by pushing to it, but `Array::flatMap` first flatten the array into a new one and then map this intermediate array into the result array or vise versa, thus degrading performance.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I will upvote, how can I also include the parent item of subquestions  in item?

`{
    type: 'subItems'
   }`

this object? 

is this the right way?:

`if(item.type === 'subItems'){
        arr.push(item);
        arr.push(...item.subItems);
      }`

Comment: @Can done, check the last snippet

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with `filter` and `map`.

```js
const currentElements = { items: [{ name: 'item', subItems: [{ name: 'item 1', type: 'item' }, { name: 'item 2', type: 'item' } ], type: 'subItems' }, { name: 'item', type: 'item' } ] };

function returnNewElments(elements) {
  return {
    items: elements.items.filter(item => item.type === 'subItems')
    .map(item => item.subItems)
    .flat()
  }
}
const newElements = returnNewElments(currentElements);
console.log(newElements);
```

Comment: is `.map(({ name, type }) => ({ name, type }))` this needed? because this properties will grow, do I need to map all properties then?

and is there not a shorter way to tackle this.

Comment: Fixed i have update my answer

Comment: @XMehdi01 not efficient, too many unnecessary intermediate arrays...

Comment: I have do another answer you can check it out!

Comment: @XMehdi01 wow, that was unexpected, `flatMap()` is actually slower! i thought it would be faster!

Comment: @XMehdi01 upvoted since you put good efforts here, nice to learn from you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `map`, you could only use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and check if `item` has property `subItems` return its items.

```js
const currentElements = { items: [{ name: 'item', subItems: [{ name: 'item 1', type: 'item' }, { name: 'item 2', type: 'item' } ], type: 'subItems' }, { name: 'item', type: 'item' } ] };

function returnNewElments(elements) {
  return {
    items: elements.items.flatMap(item => item.type == 'subItems' && item.subItems).filter(Boolean)
  }
}
const newElements = returnNewElments(currentElements);
console.log(newElements);
```

Comment: in the new Element, I just only want to have the subitems. In your example it's also adding the item which is not a subitem.

newElement must only contain `item 1` and `item 2`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Fixed, see update!

Comment: what was the code for also showing the normal items? your first answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
returnItems() {
  const items = this.currentElement.items
    .filter(item => item.type === 'subItems')
    .flatMap(item => item.subItems);
    
  return items;
}
```

The issue here is that the map function is returning an array of subItems arrays, which results in an array of arrays. Instead, you want to "flatten" these into a single array. You can achieve this with the flat or flatMap function.

Comment: This looks like the most readable, short and clean solution.